# Trying to create a dictionary and append to the list

Tags: python, list, selenium, dictionary

I was trying to scrape the data from the website [link](https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare) and when we click on the "Sterne Anzeigen" button at the bottom of the review we find the sub ratings and wanted to scrape that rating and store it in the CSV file. I was able to perform the actions like clicking on the button for each review and write code to extract the sub ratings as below

```
articles=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("index__reviewBlock__27gnB")

data=[]

for article in articles:

   try:
     element2 = article.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
   except EX.NoSuchElementException:
     pass

   for element in element2:
     ActionChains(browser).click(element).perform()

   row={}  

   Stars=article.find_elements_by_class_name("index__factor__3Z15R")


   for item in Stars:
    key = item.find_element_by_class_name("index__title__W4hOp").text
    value = item.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='index__stars__2ads4 index__medium__1wpWb index__stars__3lgvx']").get_attribute("data-score")
    row[key]=value

 data.append(row)
```

Can anyone help me to get the exact ratings since using this code I'm getting all the rating value "5"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You keep re-using *the same dict*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve this (with `requests` module and some regex logic):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

response = requests.get("https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
scores = soup.find('div',{'class':re.compile('index__reviewBlock')})

output_dict = dict()
for el in scores.find_all('h4'):
    score_label = el.text
    score_stars = el.findNext('div').find('span',{'data-score':True}).get('data-score')
    output_dict[score_label] = int(score_stars)
```

Output

```
{'Gut am Arbeitgeber finde ich': 5,
 'Arbeitsatmosphäre': 5,
 'Image': 5,
 'Work-Life-Balance': 5,
 'Karriere/Weiterbildung': 5,
 'Gehalt/Sozialleistungen': 5,
 'Umwelt-/Sozialbewusstsein': 5,
 'Kollegenzusammenhalt': 4,
 'Umgang mit älteren Kollegen': 5,
 'Vorgesetztenverhalten': 5,
 'Arbeitsbedingungen': 4,
 'Kommunikation': 5,
 'Gleichberechtigung': 5,
 'Interessante Aufgaben': 5}
```

Comment: Hi @Sebastien,Thanks for the code but I want to achieve this in Selenium.It would be great if you help me in that

Comment: it will be exactly the same, just replace `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)` by `soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
   data=[]
   row={}  

    Stars=article.find_elements_by_class_name("index__factor__3Z15R")

   for item in Stars:
       key = item.find_element_by_class_name("index__title__W4hOp").text
       value = item.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='index__stars__2ads4 
       index__medium__1wpWb index__stars__3lgvx']").get_attribute("data-score")
       row.update(key=value)

   data.append(row)
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue at all

Comment: Hi syed,Unfortunately this isn't giving the correct output